# Do modals with for-loop on Vue

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-modal

I want to create modals for cards with loops. I tried v-bind:id="masa._id" and v-bind:data-target="'#'+masa._id" but modal not working ... how to do modals in loops?

Here is my html code:

```
        <div class="row">

      <div class="col" v-for="masa in Bahce1grupA_data">

           <!-- The Masa Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade"  v-bind:id="masa._id">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
              <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title">[[masa.siparis_grup]]-[[masa.siparis_masano]]</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                      deneme
                      <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">5</span>
                      4
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  Toplam Fiyat : 30
                  Kişi Sayısı : 2

                </div>

                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Hesabı Kapat</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Masayı Değiştir</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card text-white mb-3" v-bind:class="getClass(masa.hesap_durumu)">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">[[masa.siparis_grup]]-[[masa.siparis_masano]]</h5>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="modal" v-bind:data-target="'#'+masa._id">Hesabı Aç</button>
            </div>
          </div>

      </div>
```

I concatenated # with masa._id to make sure not to interpret them as a plain string. And values of _id are totally unique for each.

and Vue part of my code is:

```
      var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#app2',
      delimiters: ['[[',']]'],
      data: {
        Bahce1grupA_data: {},
        Bahce1grupB_data: {},
        Bahce1grupC_data: {},
        Bahce1grupD_data: {},            
      },
      mounted: function() {
              polling1=setInterval(()=> {
              axios.get('/getBahce1grupA')
                  .then((response)=> {
                      this.Bahce1grupA_data = response.data;
                  })
          }, 5000);
```

Comment: what contain Bahce1grupA_data?

Comment: jsonified mongodb data.

Comment: ok, in DOM structure your modal added?

Comment: Well, I try to dynamically create them with the code above. I dont have anything related to modals anywhere else in html

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Doesn't show in the code? Doesn't open on click? Please be more specific about the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: create example on codepen or other online editor

Comment: "not working" means that html page doesnt show up at all. Normally without id loop it was showing whole page.

Comment: and I see that you display data to template by using [], I dont thing it is correct syntax. You should use {{}}
For example:
 <h4 class="modal-title">{{`${masa.siparis_grup}-${masa.siparis_masano}`}}</h4>

Comment: I use [[ ]] because it is working with Flask.

Comment: var vm = new Vue({
          el: '#app2',
          delimiters: ['[[',']]'],
          data: {
            Bahce1grupA_data: {},
            Bahce1grupB_data: {},
            Bahce1grupC_data: {},
            Bahce1grupD_data: {},            
          },
          mounted: function() {
                  polling1=setInterval(()=> {
                  axios.get('/getBahce1grupA')
                      .then((response)=> {
                          this.Bahce1grupA_data = response.data;
                      })

Comment: what return console.log(response.data)?
and why you get data every 5 seconds?

Comment: I need to show the latest entry for each card. Thats why I need to check db every 5 secs. But because of this ,new modals with new ids are created each time.

Comment: response.data : [{"_id": "5e4c5c7921cf75b94455e99a", "adisyon": "adisyon_1", "garson_id": "12345", "siparis_alan": "Bah\u00e7e1", "siparis_grup": "A", "siparis_masano": "1", "siparisler": [{"satir": "A\u00e7\u0131k \u00c7ay", "bolum": "drink", "birim_fiyat": 25, "satir_toplam_fiyat": 50, "adet": 2}, {"satir": "Sade T\u00fcrk Kahvesi", "bolum": "drink", "birim_fiyat": 25, "satir_toplam_fiyat": 25, "adet": 1}], "kisi_sayisi": "4", "masa_fiyat": 75, "hesap_durumu": "hesap acik", "not": "", "odeme_yontemi": "", "zaman_pulu": "2020-02-19 00:51:53.216000"}, {"_id": "5e4c69fb5d7571bed9e96949", ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added prefix as such : v-bind:id="'kimlik'+masa._id" and v-bind:data-target="'#kimlik'+masa._id" just because _id starts with numbers. And it worked.